# Manga where a man is being haunted by his dead female childhood friend that follows him around

Tags: story-identification, manga

It’s a manga where this guy is being haunted by his dead female childhood friend. He is an adult who is trying to get himself a girlfriend. Though his childhood friend keeps getting in his way.

I was at the part where he finally found a girl he likes, but his childhood friend is skeptical. The childhood friend thinks she is no good and tries to tell him. He thinks that she doesn’t want him to be with anyone, so he starts wishing she would just disappear.

By the way the girl that the guy likes can see his dead childhood friend, and she also has one following her around too. Though she pretends like she can’t see that dead childhood friend.

The last time I read the manga was about 3 years ago. I don’t know if it was based off, or made from an anime. I do remember that the childhood friend was wearing a hoodie. I don’t remember if it was on the cover though. Probably was I just can’t recall.

Comment: Hi there and welcome to SciFi.SE. Can you please take a look at [this list](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question) and [edit] in any more information you can remember? For example: when did you read this? Can you recall if it was it based on an anime, or if it was inspired by an anime?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think it is the Chinese webcomic *[Guarding](https://www.mangaupdates.com/series.html?id=123090)*, aka *My Guardian Angel* in [the official English translation](https://tapas.io/series/myguardianangel).

[image: Lin, shown in her hoodie]

> Lin Xiaoyou, childhood friend of Xi Yu, died at the age of 14, but her spirit refused to pass onto the afterlife. Instead, she stuck around and became Yu's "guardian angel" due to a promise she made to him. Under Xiaoyou's constant guarding, Yu hasn't had a single girlfriend even though he's already 24. Being in a proper relationship has become his goal in life, but such a simple wish brings about a series of terrifying incidents. Is Xiaoyou really a "guardian angel", or is she actually an "evil spirit"?!

[Chapter 8, "She Can See Me"](https://tapas.io/episode/1219352), is the episode where the girl who can see her is introduced, complete with the protagonist wishing she would disappear.

Found with a search for `manhua ghost "childhood friend"`

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that you're looking for [*Anhohana: The Flower We Saw That Day*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anohana:_The_Flower_We_Saw_That_Day)?

> In Chichibu, Saitama, a group of six sixth-grade-age childhood friends drift apart after one of them, Meiko "Menma" Honma, dies in an accident. Five years[3] after the incident, the leader of the group, Jinta Yadomi, has withdrawn from society, does not attend high school, and lives as a recluse. One summer day, the ghost of an older-looking Menma appears beside him and asks to have a wish granted, reasoning that she cannot pass on into the afterlife until it is fulfilled. At first, he only tries to help her minimally because he thinks he is hallucinating. But since Menma does not remember what her wish is, Jinta gathers his estranged friends together once again, believing that they are the key to solving this problem. All of the group joins him, though most of them do so reluctantly. However, things grow increasingly complicated when his friends accuse him of not being able to get over Menma's death, as they cannot see her and believe Jinta is hallucinating. Menma shows her presence to the group in order to prove that she is indeed real. All the group members eventually wish to shoulder the blame for Menma's death and long-hidden feelings among the group are rekindled. The group struggles as they grow from trying to help Menma move on and help each other move on as well.

It started as an anime, but there was a manga adaptation. Also, I have not found reference to a girl he likes who also has a ghost of a childhood friend following her. Also, I haven't found a cover that has her in a hoody.

[image: Cover of the first volume of Anhohana: The Flower We Saw That Day]

Found with a search for `manga ghost "childhood friend"`, this being the best match out of the half dozen I found with this plotline.