# Manhwa about a girl who died in a car crash and then came back as a ghost, because she made a promise to a boy to always protect him

Tags: story-identification, manga, ghost

I'm looking for a manhwa, if that's what you call when it's in color form. But anyways, I do remember reading it and I somehow forgot all about it and can't seem to remember the name but I do remember the description talking about a childhood friend (a girl) who died in a car crash then got revived, because she made a promise to a boy to always protect him. Whenever he tries to talk to a girl, the ghost girl would always come between them and ruin it.

Comment: I've marked this as a duplicate, since you commented that it was correct, but you can still accept, and get some points reward for doing so.

Answer (score 2):

Sound like this might be ***[My Guardian Angel](https://www.mangaupdates.com/series.html?id=123090)***.

> Lin Xiaoyou, childhood friend of Xi Yu, died at the age of 14, but her spirit refused to pass onto the afterlife. Instead, she stuck around and became Yu's "guardian angel" due to a promise she made to him. Under Xiaoyou's constant guarding, Yu hasn't had a single girlfriend even though he's already 24. Being in a proper relationship has become his goal in life, but such a simple wish brings about a series of terrifying incidents. Is Xiaoyou really a "guardian angel", or is she actually an "evil spirit"?!

While the girl was alive, she promised the male lead that even if she died, she'd be his guardian angel and protect him.

She was subsequently killed in a car accident when they were both 14 years old, but in the decade which has passed since then, her ghost (which only the male lead can see and hear) has continued to haunt him, deliberately sabotaging his attempts to form relationships with other women.

It also appears that as a result of dying so young, her ghost never matured psychologically beyond adolescence, so she still asks the male lead to play games with her, even though he's now a working man in his mid-twenties.

[image]

[image]

Comment: If accepted, it will be a dupe of https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/245186/23243

Comment: Bro how the hell did you find it! Are you a god of findings? Tysm man

Comment: @Eran -If this answer is correct, please don't forget to mark it as accepted by clicking on the check mark beneath the voting buttons. You'll know if you've done it correctly, because it'll turn green, and you'll gain +2 reputation. Thanks.